# Matching and adding column to data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am going crazy about this one. I am trying to add a new column to a data frame *DF1*, based on values found in another data frame *DF2*. This is how they look,

DF1=

```
    Date         Amount      Currency
0   2014-08-20   -20000000   EUR
1   2014-08-20   -12000000   CAD
2   2014-08-21   10000       EUR
3   2014-08-21   20000       USD
4   2014-08-22   25000       USD
```

DF2=

```
    NAME       OPEN
0   EUR        10
1   CAD        20
2   USD        30
```

Now, I would like to create a new column in *DF1*, named *'Amount (Local)'*, where each amount in *'Amount'* is multipled with the correct matching value found in *DF2* yielding a result,

DF1=

```
    Date         Amount      Currency   Amount (Local)
0   2014-08-20   -20000000   EUR        -200000000
1   2014-08-20   -12000000   CAD        -240000000
2   2014-08-21   10000       EUR        100000
3   2014-08-21   20000       USD        600000
4   2014-08-22   25000       USD        750000
```

If there exists a method for adding a column to *DF1* based on a *function*, instead of just multiplication as the above problem, that would be very much appreciated also.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` from a dict of your second df (in my case it is called df1. yours is DF2), and then multiply the result of this by the amount:

```
In [65]:

df['Amount (Local)'] = df['Currency'].map(dict(df1[['NAME','OPEN']].values)) * df['Amount']
df
Out[65]:
             Date    Amount Currency  Amount (Local)
index                                               
0      2014-08-20 -20000000      EUR      -200000000
1      2014-08-20 -12000000      CAD      -240000000
2      2014-08-21     10000      EUR          100000
3      2014-08-21     20000      USD          600000
4      2014-08-22     25000      USD          750000
```

So breaking this down, `map` will match the value against the value in the dict key, in this case we are matching `Currency` against the `NAME` key, the value in the dict is the `OPEN` values, the result of this would be:

```
In [66]:

df['Currency'].map(dict(df1[['NAME','OPEN']].values))
Out[66]:
index
0        10
1        20
2        10
3        30
4        30
Name: Currency, dtype: int64
```

We then simply multiply this series against the `Amount` column from `df` (DF1 in your case) to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @EdChum ! Works like a charm. Thanks for the break down as well. I tried @shx2 solution too, which seems to work _only_ if all of the currencies are the same in both data frames. In my real work, I do have a lot more currency tickers in my `DF2` whence the second solution is more general. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Use fancy-indexing to create a currency array aligned with your data in `df1`, then use it in multiplication, and assign the result to a new column in `df1`:

```
import pandas as pd

ccy_series = pd.Series([10,20,30], index=['EUR', 'CAD', 'USD'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [-200, -120, 1, 2, 2.5], 'ccy': ['EUR', 'CAD', 'EUR', 'USD', 'USD']})

aligned_ccy = ccy_series[df1.ccy].reset_index(drop=True)
aligned_ccy
=> 
0    10
1    20
2    10
3    30
4    30
dtype: int64

df1['amount_local'] = df1.amount *aligned_ccy

df1
=> 
   amount  ccy  amount_local
0  -200.0  EUR         -2000
1  -120.0  CAD         -2400
2     1.0  EUR            10
3     2.0  USD            60
4     2.5  USD            75
```